# Firebase Emulator --export-on-exit not working properly (Windows 10)

Tags: firebase, import, export, firebase-tools

I have been experimenting with using Firebase emulators to decrease the number of reads/writes against my actual Firestore db while I am developing a web app. More specifically, I would like to create some re-useable test data from the Emulator UI to work with as I am developing my app, before I deploy to production.

I saw there are options to export data from the Emulator UI and re-import them in later sessions, so after following the docs, I have setup a simple npm script in `package.json`:
`"em-startup": "firebase emulators:start --export-on-exit=data"`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#export_and_import_emulator_data

When I run `npm run em-startup`, the emulator starts up as expected, I can create collections/docs, etc. in the Emulator UI:

```
> ww@0.1.0 em-startup
> firebase emulators:start --export-on-exit=data

i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
!  emulators: It seems that you are running multiple instances of the emulator suite for project drew-daniels-wheres-waldo. This may result in unexpected behavior.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log
i  pubsub: Pub/Sub Emulator logging to pubsub-debug.log
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: build
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ localhost:9099 │ http://localhost:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Database       │ localhost:9000 │ http://localhost:4000/database  │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting        │ localhost:5000 │ n/a                             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Pub/Sub        │ localhost:8085 │ n/a                             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Storage        │ localhost:9199 │ http://localhost:4000/storage   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
```

but when I `ctrl+C` to stop the emulator, PowerShell generates the following output:

```
i  emulators: Received SIGINT (Ctrl-C) for the first time. Starting a clean shutdown.
i  emulators: Please wait for a clean shutdown or send the SIGINT (Ctrl-C) signal again to stop right now.
i  Automatically exporting data using --export-on-exit "data" please wait for the export to finish...

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Error: Storage Emulator Rules runtime exited unexpectedly.
i  Found running emulator hub for project (my-project-name) at http://localhost:4400
i  Exporting data to: C:\Users\MyUserName\my\folder\project\data
i  emulators: Received export request. Exporting data to C:\Users\MyUserName\my\folder\project\data.
```

Additionally, no matter what file path I pass as a parameter in `--export-on-exit=` seems to be taken into account, and all that gets exported are files like these output to my project's root directory:

[image]

Here is my full project file structure:

[image]

It appears that the Firebase emulator is not gracefully shutting down with `ctrl+C` and consequently the data from my emulator UI session are not being successfully output and saved in my `data` directory.

What I have tried:

- Changing the relative file paths from `./data` to `data`
- Ensuring all java.exe instances are closed (via task manager)
- Restarting my computer

**EDIT**
There is an open issue on Github regarding this as it appears to be a bug that more people are experiencing. I posted a comment detailing what I'm seeing from my end.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3092

Comment: Same issue today but on mac. I'm using firebase-tools version 10.7.0. The work around I'm using is to manually run `firebase emulators:export ./emulators` (or in your case `./data`) before terminating the emulator and not using `--export-on-exit`.

Comment: @skwny maybe you saved me weeks of work

Comment: To avoid restarting your computer ... You can kill all emulator processes using the npm package 'kill-port'.

Answer (score 3):

The edited doc is exported in a separate folder with name like **'firebase-export-1654933704513LgLzMo'** on exiting the emulator. you have rename it to **'firebase-export'** so that the import is done from that file once you start the emulator.

The script is like this:

```bash
firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore --import ./firebase-export --export-on-exit ./firebase-export
```

You have to keep deleting the old one and renaming the latest one to import the latest data.

Comment: Sometimes this works - sometimes it doesn't, esp. when the .firebase folder still exists and a new folder is created. At that point, neither folder has up-to-date content. I'm assuming I'd have to merge them somehow. Any way to make it *always* work? (p.s. Re-specifying the same value for `--export-on-exit` is unnecessary)

Answer (score 2):

My use-case isn't exactly the same, because I was both importing and exporting the data (so that the emulator data would persist across restarts), whereas your example command line doesn't specify that you want to import the data on start-up.

That said, I was running the emulator explicitly specifying both the import and export directories, like this: `firebase emulators:start --import ./.emulator-data --export-on-exit=./.emulator-data`, and getting the same issue as you describe, with the export going to auto-generated directory names `firebase-export-${guid}` on each shutdown instead of the directory name I specified.

What fixed it for me was to stop specifying the export directory twice, and only specify it for the import argument. According to [the firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure): "If `--import` is used, the export path defaults to the same; for example: `firebase emulators:start --import=./data-path --export-on-exit`"

For the record, I'm using `"firebase-tools": "^11.24.0"`, and am also running on Windows 10.

So my command line is now `firebase emulators:start --import ./.emulator-data --export-on-exit` and the current state of the emulator is being saved into the `.emulator-data` folder each time the emulator shuts down, as desired.

That command is also able to start up when the `.emulator-data` folder does not exist, so if your goal is to populate your emulator once manually and then load it on start thereafter, you could use the version of the command with both `--import` and `--export-on-exit`, populate your data, shut down the emulator, then remove the `--export-on-exit` for subsequent invocations.

Comment: I can't get this to work on 11.25.3 :(

Comment: No ... won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and i solved this problem creating a .bat with the follow command:

```
    @ECHO Starting emulator...

    call firebase emulators:start --only auth,functions,firestore,pubsub,storage --import=./firebase_export --export-on-exit

    pause
```

If we don't use `--only <modules>`, like the example, always when exit, the emulator will export in differents folders.

Probably this is a bug from firebase-tools, but this workaround worked to me.

Comment: You don't need a .bat file ... just add a command to your package scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Vite, set this on `vite.config.ts`:

`server: { watch: { usePolling: true }}`

The symptoms are caused by the Vite dev server holding locks on nested folders (which can prevent the emulator from renaming its snapshots on Windows).

Credits/Source: [bmcbarron - github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3092#issuecomment-1491220706)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **firebase-tools** version `13.5.2` on **Windows 11**.

In my case I was both importing and exporting data using this command:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./firebase-export --export-on-exit
```

But the issue here was with the data export which was generating the `firebase-export-{uid}` folder, while showing this error on exit:

```
i  Exporting data to: C:\Users\user\Documents\Dev\firebase-export

i  emulators: Received export request. Exporting data to C:\Users\user\Documents\Dev\firebase-export.

!  emulators: Export failed: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Dev\firebase-export-1711276697951kF5xq2' -> 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Dev\firebase-export'

!  Export request failed, see emulator logs for more information.

!  Automatic export to "./firebase-export" failed, going to exit now...

i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
```

The import works just fine after renaming the folder.

It seems that *firebase emulator* first exports the data to the folder with uid `firebase-export-{uid}` then fails to rename the folder due to the lack of permission on **Windows**.

**Note:** I tried using Linux for instance on a virtual machine and it worked seamlessly without any issues.

### Solution :

I had to use another folder outside the `C:/Users/user/Documents` folder in order to export  the data correctly, for instance I used a separate folder inside another partition `D:/Dev/firebase-export` and it worked just fine. Just try to avoid Windows folders and you will be fine.